# How to make map-derived variable reflect the current $uri?

Tags: nginx

A request for `/olddir1/img.jpeg` using the following nginx configuration will do a correct internal redirect to `/newdir1/img.jpeg` but it will leave the variable `$extra_uri` set to the value it would have during the first rewrite cycle, that is `/olddir1/img.jpeg`.

Just before executing the `rewrite` directive, `$alias_uri` and `$extra_uri` will have the following values, all correct:

- `$alias_uri`: `/newdir1/img.jpeg`
- `$extra_uri`: `/olddir1/img.jpeg`

After the `rewrite` directive is run, setting $uri to `/newdir1/img.jpeg`, the variables will have the following values:

- `$alias_uri`: `/newdir1/img.jpeg`
- `$extra_uri`: `/olddir1/img.jpeg`

`$alias_uri` has the correct value (nothing has matched in the `map`, so the default is being used, i.e. the current `$uri`). `$extra_uri` instead has a stale value.

**How come `$extra_uri` isn't set to the new `$uri`?**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name     'test.example.local';

    location / {
        root '/var/www/test/content';

        set $alias_uri $example__alias_uri;
        set $extra_uri $example__extra_uri;

        if ($alias_uri != $uri) {
            rewrite ^ $alias_uri last;
        }

        add_header X-Alias "uri: >$uri< alias_uri: >$alias_uri<" always;
        add_header X-Extra "uri: >$uri< extra_uri: >$extra_uri<" always;

        try_files $uri =404;
}

map $uri $example__alias_uri {
    default $uri;

    ~/olddir1(?<file>/[^/]*)$ /newdir1$file;
    ~/olddir2(?<file>/[^/]*)$ /newdir2$file;
}

map $uri $example__extra_uri {
    default $uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking the maps as `volatile` makes this problem go away.

```
map $uri $example__alias_uri {
    volatile;
    default $uri;

    ~/olddir1(?<file>/[^/]*)$ /newdir1$file;
    ~/olddir2(?<file>/[^/]*)$ /newdir2$file;
}

map $uri $example__extra_uri {
    volatile;
    default $uri;
}
```

It seems that maps are evaluated only once during the very first rewrite phase and never afterwards.